# Text box validation in ASP.NET to show only available option from table

Tags: asp.net, validation

On my ASP page , click will put the vedor: . I do have total 787 vendor (with vendorCode - VendorName combination)in my table . and I want when Clint start typing value,its must only show the relevant value.

For example if user start with "A" it will only shows option for the VedorCode and vendorName started with A . and filter out data as per user input.

Please advice !!

Comment: You can try on text changed and use LIKE to search have you try that?

Comment: @KratosMafia I am sorry but not sure how to use that..could you please give me some example so that i can try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for something like jQuery Autocomplete. 
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/